# Should AWS Security groups allow internet traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

Ok, so I created a default Elastic Beanstalk Application and getting this reported as High Risk, and happens on all Regions that are connected to the VPC Network (which is not a public IP, only the Load Balancer subnets are).

> AWS Security groups allow internet traffic

The site is public, so shouldn't this be normal?  Or is there a way to not allow Security Groups internet traffic and still keep the site publicly visible to users who visit it?  I'm just not sure if there is a way to fix this High Security Risk that's being reported.  Is this an actual Security Risk?  If so, any idea how to fix this problem?  I am also receiving the following Security Risk here:

> AWS Default Security Group does not restrict all traffic

Why would I want to restrict all traffic?  Is there a way to do this and still make the site publicly visible on the internet?  Please note, running a wordpress site.

Should this not allow Internet Access?  Sorry if this is a dumb question.

And seeing this as well:

> AWS EC2 instances with Public IP and associated with Security Groups have Internet Access

I don't think these instances need access to the internet to be displayed on the internet, but not sure how to fix this.

**EDIT**
Here are my Security Groups inbound and outbound rules:
[image: Security Group Inbound]
[image: Security Group Outbound]

Do I need to remove the Inbound Rule for this in order to fix this, but still keep internet working on the site?  This is the Security Group for the VPC Network, btw, is this the correct one?

Load Balancer Settings from EB here:

[image: Load Balancer]

Comment: Post your Load Balancer and EB instance security group settings / screenshots. We can't guess what you've got there and why.

Comment: Ok, does this help you any? What I've read online, says you have to have Inbound set to port 80 and outbound set to All traffic in order to have a public site accessible to everyone on the internet.  Is this not correct?

Comment: This is the Security Group attached to the VPC btw, is this the one you need?

Comment: Do I need to remove Inbound and Outbound on the VPC Security Group and the Load Balancer would run it instead?

Comment: I am now thinking this is due to VPC, which I don't even think is needed on the Elastic Beanstalk Environment, but was on the older Environment before.  Everything is streaming from the site itself, so I think it has to do with the VPC, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > AWS Security groups allow internet traffic

Normal for a web server

> > AWS Default Security Group does not restrict all traffic

Remove all the rules from the default security group, and use a custom security group.

Update: Best practice is not to use the default security group, and to remove all rules from that group. That way anything that uses the default security group is obviously using a default rather than a deliberate selection, which generally means it needs attention and to be changed to use an appropriate security group.

> > AWS EC2 instances with Public IP and associated with Security Groups have Internet Access

That's the whole point of it I think

Comment: If I'm going to change to a different Security Group, what's the point of removing all rules from the default Security Group?  Just curious, and thank you very much for your input on this.

Comment: I believe other sites on here might be using the default security group.  I don't think the site I am working on is.  So I don't think removing all rules will help.  I did edit it to only allow ports 80 and 443 for inbound, and All traffic for outbound.  So hopefully that fixes the majority of these issues.

Comment: Best practice is not to use the default security group, and to remove all rules from that group. That way anything that uses the default security group is obviously using a default rather than a deliberate selection, which generally means it needs attention and to be changed to use an appropriate security group.

Comment: Thanks for the more details on this.  You da Man, Tim!

Comment: You're welcome. You learn a lot in AWS preparing for the security certification, and going through PCI compliance for an AWS based system.